# Add price (3 500) only selects first character

Tags: html, numbers, format, twig

Why I try to add some numbers like this:

```
{# firstprice is 3 500 #}
{# secondprice is 400 #}
{{ firstprice + secondprice }}
{# result is 403 #}
```

How can I make sure he can see the first value correct? That it's three thousand and 500 ..

Answer (score 0):

Use `|number_format` [twig filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html):

```
{{ firstprice|number_format(0,'','') + secondprice|number_format(0,'','') }}
```

Comment: add arguments `(0,'','')`, try again :)